# Command line Jabber client

Tags: macos, terminal, jabber

Does anyone know of a command line jabber client that would run in OS X in the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mcabber` ([man](https://mcabber.com/files/mcabber.1.html)) is available via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: This is a console client, not a command line one.

Comment: @shellholic What's your point? He explicitly mentions Terminal.

Comment: @Corey Then please click the checkmark you see next to my post to mark this answer as "accepted", and your question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: In a console client, there is a user interface in a terminal. In a command line client, you type commands after commands in the terminal. For example, in the field of file manipulation, "`ls`, `cd`, `mv`, `cp`" are command line client and `mc` (Midnight Commander) is a console client.

Comment: By the way. I think this is why I couldn't find what I was looking for. I was searching for 'command line jabber client'. Now that I've searched for 'console jabber client' I'm finding mcabber.

Comment: @shellholic Please cite your sources.

Comment: References from Wikipedia: [Console application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_application), [Command line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_interface)

Comment: @shell How does your understanding of the definition of command-line program fit with [interactive programming language interpreters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_line_interface#Programming_languages_in_interactive_mode) like Python's? *Interactive* mode, not "process this source file" mode! Just type `python` and see what happens. The only difference left, IMO, is the sophistication of output handling (line by line in CLI, complete control over display in console application). Which is probably not what the poster cared for in his question.

Comment: (Sorry for post hijacking but this discussion interest me) If you push me in the corner and really want to draw a line between console and command line, here is my suggestion: if you can do it without cursor motion (ANSI escape), it is a command line app. If you need cursor motion, it is a console app. For the interpreter/shell case, it's more the first than the second.

Comment: For example, the Jabber partial client here: [sendxmpp](http://sendxmpp.platon.sk/) is a command line one. You can pipe to it. `echo "my message" | sendxmpp someone@jabber.org`

Answer (score 2):

There is a Perl script that can be usefull, but only for sending: [sendxmpp](http://sendxmpp.platon.sk/)

Comment: It doen't work with different domain (when Jabber server was moved to another domain name, but virtual hosts remain with the old name).